# Visual studio 2010 change remove administrator manifest right is not working anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Basic 2010 Console application,

That I created a couple of months ago,

I needed to prevent administrative request,

So I just Went to “View Windows Settings”,

And changed the app.manifest “requestedExecutionLevel” to:

```
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

And now the executable has a special administrative icon that differentiates it from others.

The code worked well and did not ask me for administrative rights,

But now it is asking me!!

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now it is asking me!!

That's entirely normal.  When you use "requireAdministrator" then Windows is going to display the UAC prompt to warn the user.

What was not normal is that it didn't display the prompt before.  Otherwise easily explained, Windows only displays the prompt when necessary.  If you are already running Visual Studio elevated for example and press F5 then you won't see it.  The only surefire way to *not* get the prompt is to use "asInvoker" instead of "requireAdministrator".  But then of course your program won't run with admin rights.  If you need them then your program will fail.

If your real question is "can I get elevation without a prompt?" then the answer is: absolutely not.

Comment: There's nothing in that blog post that disagrees with my answer.  You are just misunderstanding what that change does.

Comment: OK, i guess i misunderstood